# What data type in C# would I use for translating english to pig latin in Visual Studio Forms?

Tags: c#

What data type in C# would I use for translating english to pig latin in Visual Studio Forms?
Is it a string or what. I only need to know what type data type would be used. I' only have to translate a single word.

Comment: Uhm... what? If you are translating a `String` in English to some other language then probably a `string` would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

`string` would be fine:

```
    string english = "wall";
       string pigLatin = "";
       string firstLetter;
       string restOfWord;
       string vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
       int letterPos;

      foreach (string word in english.Split())
      {
          firstLetter = word.Substring(0, 1);
          restOfWord = word.Substring(1, word.Length - 1);
          letterPos = vowels.IndexOf(firstLetter);
          if (letterPos == -1)
          {
              //it's a consonant
              pigLatin = restOfWord + firstLetter + "ay";
          }
          else
          {
              //it's a vowel
              pigLatin = word + "way";
          }
        }        
//pigLatin should be "allway", I think.
```